# Python - Printing the values of a while loop to lists

Tags: python

I have a python code that keeps running until the value of **number_of_prints** reach 20, while its lower than 20, it keeps printing random numbers from **(0,20)** using the randint function

Code:

```
from random import *

mylist = []
number_of_prints = 0
maximum = 20
x = randint(0,20)

while number_of_prints < maximum:
    print (x)
    x = randint(0,20)
    number_of_prints += 1
```

It prints 20 different numbers. How do I print these numbers in a list?
example
Set mylist to have each number from X as an integer inside it

```
print mylist
>>> [1,3,4,2,6,5,8,7,9,11,10,13,12,14,16,17,19,20,18]
```

Comment: Do you want every number (0, 20) in a random order, or do you want 21 random numbers between 0 and 20?

Comment: Your code doesn't print 20 different numbers. You never check, if the current number has been printed before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append them to a list

```
from random import *

mylist = []
number_of_prints = 0
maximum = 20
x = randint(0,20)
r_list=[]

while number_of_prints < maximum:
    print (x)
    r_list.append(x)
    x = randint(0,20)
    number_of_prints += 1
```